# How can I use only the month and day of Date.today in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display recent and upcoming anniversaries. Since dates are stored with year, the following code displays an empty array because none of my folks were married this year:

```
  ann=Anniversary.where(anniversary: Date.today-7..Date.today+7)
```

So, how can I remove the year delimiter?

Comment: Have you considered denormalizing the data and storing something like a day of year (`Time.now.yday`) in a separate indexed column? I'm not an expert on all database technologies around but I don't think many would be able to execute such query effectively.

Comment: What database are you using? Typically the way you would approch the problem is to use the database functions to extract the month and day from the `anniversaries.anniversery` column and then construct a date this year which you use for the comparison.

Comment: @JanVítek there is a slight problem with using `yday` in that it shifts one day forward during a leap year after februari 29th. Otherwise you make a pretty good point.

Comment: Using Rails 7 postgresql. I added new column called yday and thought I could populate the data via console with an update_all, but I can't make that work correctly. I haven't given up. Jan: this is not an issue because I will use yday only to select the recent and short-term anniversaries; the true date will be used in the view, modified to show mmdd.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the SQL [EXTRACT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_extract.asp) method for this like below:

```
anniversaries = Anniversary.where('EXTRACT(month from anniversary) = ? AND EXTRACT(day from anniversary) IN (?)', Date.today.month, Date.today.day..(Date.today.day + 7))
```

Comment: You're right about EXTRACT but I have clue how you think that query will work.

Comment: So I wound up using the birthdays gem, rather than go the SQL route. (the gem does it for me). Easy to use with the "find_anniversaries_for" (range)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "transpose" a date to the current year you can do it in Postgres by extracting the month and day and constructing a new date:

```ruby
Anniversary.where(
  %q{
     MAKE_DATE(
      DATE_PART('year', CURRENT_DATE)::int,
      DATE_PART('month', anniversaries.anniversery)::int,
      DATE_PART('day', anniversaries.anniversery)::int
    ) BETWEEN 
       CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7 days'
    AND
       CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '7 days'
  }
)
```

I would really recommend this over using the day of the year since it doesn't suffer an off by one error when its a leap year.

I'm using DATE_PART instead of EXTRACT simply because its slightly easier if you want to convert this into Arel if you choose to do so at some point.

If you want to get fancy you could move this into a PL/pgSQL function:

```plpgsql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transpose_date(x date)
RETURNS date AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN MAKE_DATE(
     DATE_PART('year', CURRENT_DATE)::int
     DATE_PART('month', x)::int,
     DATE_PART('day', x)::int
   );
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```ruby
Anniversary.where(
  %q{
     WHERE transpose_date(anniversaries.anniversery)
     BETWEEN 
       CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7 days'
    AND
       CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '7 days'
    }
)
```

Note that this requires you to switch to SQL schema dumps in order for the function to be present when recreating the schema from the schema dumps.

Comment: This is the first time I have ever written PL/pgSQL so please don't make too much fun of me.